# How to initialize array in PHP with a variable value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm running into a issue with PHP array. Basically I want to sort a 2D array by its value. If I initialize literal array value and sort it works fine. But the literal array value is created at run time and assigned to a variable that is further assigned to array which is suppose to sort but it is not sorting with variable assigned value to array. In other languages I have worked we use & symbol before a variable to get its literal value, not sure what I use in PHP.

Here is the example that works fine and it is sorting by age

```
$age = array("Giselle"=>"25", "Amara"=>"15", "Josephine"=>"28", "Penelope"=>"18" ); 
asort($age);
```

Here is the same example with variable assigned to array which doesn't sort

```
$custprof = '"Giselle"=>"25", "Amara"=>"15", "Josephine"=>"28", "Penelope"=>"18"';
$age = array($custprof); 
asort($age);
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your second version does not have an array with four elements. That is an array containing _one_ single element, and the value of that element is the _text value_ `"Giselle"=>"25", "Amara"=>"15", "Josephine"=>"28", "Penelope"=>"18"`. And trying to "sort" _one_ single value, is of course utterly pointless.

Comment: That is what my requirement is to sort the array by age, even with numeric age value it is not sorting, it sorts well when the array is assigned with literal text value. Can you pls write a line of code how you would do?

Comment: second version assigns values to array If I loop thru it I can print elements

Comment: _"second version assigns values to array"_ - no, not values in _plural_, just _value_ - a single one. _"If I loop thru it I can print elements"_ - that doesn't change the fact that you are looping over just one single element then.

Comment: You need to learn to differentiate between _code_, and _data_.

Comment: Why would you have a string like that in your variable? If you want a string value from an array, you should json_encode it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$custprof = '"Giselle"=>"25", "Amara"=>"15", "Josephine"=>"28", "Penelope"=>"18"';
eval( '$age = array(' . $custprof . ');' ); 
asort( $age );
```

Comment: If something can be done without `eval()`, it should be done without.  If anything in the 'array' comes from user input this is a huge security risk.

Comment: He can validate the string by regex before doing eval. If he doesn't want to use eval he can use explode funcation.

Comment: Explode is a better solution indeed. I've personally never came across a functionality where eval is a good solution.  You should always avoid it. In this case, the first question is: where does that string come from. If they want a string value, why not use json?

Comment: @SidAhmed please take a look at his other answer. This one might work, but ain't good at all.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid security risks you can use explode function like below.

```
$custprof = '"Giselle"=>"25", "Amara"=>"15", "Josephine"=>"28", "Penelope"=>"18"';
$custprof = explode('", "', $custprof);

$age = [];
foreach( $custprof as $single_custprof )
{
  $array     = explode('"=>"', $single_custprof);
  $key       = str_replace('"', "", $array[0]);
  $value     = str_replace('"', "", $array[1]);

  $age[$key] = $value;
}

asort( $age );
```